# Is "alcohol custody" a legit term?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, terminology

Here in Malaysia, some pubs allow customers to keep their alcohol beverage (bottles or cans) with the pubs under some terms and conditions.

What is the most suitable term for such service? Is "custody" suitable? "Alcohol custody"?

Update on the flow:

1. Customer A visit Pub A and ordered 3 Chivas Regal 18 years (1L each
   total 3L)
2. End of the night customer consumed 2L.
3. Customer ‘keep’ the balance 1L with the Pub A.
4. Pub A recorded the customer detail and balance of the beverage.
5. The next time the same customer return he/she can request the balance alcohol (1L) for enjoyment.

Comment: 'Corkage' is when a customer brings their own alcoholic drink with them and pays a fee to an establishment to be able to drink it on the premises, but I am not sure if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: @4 You need to describe *exactly* what this service is, how it's charged for (if it is), and an example of the conditions imposed. I've never come across a storage service, if that's what you're describing.

Comment: I’ve added the flow for better understanding.

Comment: The term used depends on local law and custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can comment on this subject with considerable authority from a U.S. perspective, having consumed vast quantities of alcoholic beverages over many years in countless North American drinking venues.

I've not heard the term "custody" used to describe the practice, but a number of bars and pubs provide lockers for customers to store their own preferred brands of wine and liquor. Depending on the policies of the establishment, customers may pay for a locker or they may be awarded the privilege with regular patronage or VIP status. [HERE](http://www.latimes.com/food/la-fo-lockers-20150606-story.html) is an article with photos and details.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, the term "alcohol custody" arises in connection with possession of and responsibility for distilled spirits during transportation at stages prior to retail sale.

Here, for example, are excerpts from "[Control of Alcohol and Drug Use: Coverage of Maintenance of Way (MOW) Employees and Retrospective Regulatory Review-Based Amendments](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2016/06/10/2016-13058/control-of-alcohol-and-drug-use-coverage-of-maintenance-of-way-mow-employees-and-retrospective)," an administrative rule promulgated by the U.S. Federal Railroad Administration on June 10, 2016:

> Because reasonable suspicion and reasonable cause testing share the same check box on DOT's **drug and alcohol chain of custody forms**, FRA's MIS data does not distinguish between tests conducted under mandatory reasonable suspicion authority and tests conducted under discretionary reasonable cause.
>
> ...
>
> FRA believes this sentence is confusing because FRA is proposing, in § 219.203(c), to allow only PAT breath alcohol testing, although such testing should be recorded on DOT's **alcohol custody and control form**.

And from "[Services We Cater For Ethanol / **Alcohol Custody Transfer** in Distilleries](http://www.smoothflowmeters.com/distilleries.html)" on the Smooth Flowmeters website:

> In a sug[a]r mill, Extra Neutral Alcohol (ENA), and other alcohol products are generated in the Distillery section. The alcohols are further sent to the respective end user in a Refinery, chemical or Pharma unit for further use. **Custody transfer of alcohol** after production becomes mandatory.

That concept is quite different from the notion of "alcohol custody" in Malaysia, to judge from [this person-to-person advertisement](https://my.carousell.com/p/zouk-main-room-alcohol-custody-card-50825520/?hl=en) on Carousell:

> Zouk Main Room **Alcohol Custody Card** [in] Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia.
>
> Looking for a night out at Zouk?
>
> I am selling my **bottle custody card** at RM 250. It can admit 2 persons with the card. It is much cheaper than buying a new bottle. Hurry! It expires 9th May.

The ad includes a photo of the "custody card" that the bar issued to the seller. The fifth bullet point of the "Terms & Conditions" on the inside cover establishes this term/condition:

> - This card is strictly non-transferrable only the owner of the card may claim the bottle.

—so it's not clear whether your RM 250 would buy the remainder of the bottle being held in custody by Zouk or only an interesting, collectable "custody card." As a matter of law, the answer to that question depends on whether the condition that the card is "strictly non-transferable" means simply that it can't be used by someone other than its current legal owner (that is, that the legal owner of the card can't lend it to someone else for the evening, for example, but is free to sell the card to someone else, who then becomes the card's "owner" under the card's "Terms & Conditions") or whether sale of the card to a new owner would qualify as an illicit "transfer," meaning that the card's original owner cannot legally to sell it  to anyone else. Presumably, the person trying to sell the alcohol custody card is taking the former interpretation of the card's conditions of use, and it is true that those conditions do not explicitly state that the card may not be sold to a new owner.

In any event, the Malaysian government seems to have adopted both "alcohol custody" and "bottle custody" as formal legal terms to describe the licensed storage of a specific bottle of alcohol at a particular pub for consumption by a certain individual owner/custody card holder.